# FullCalendar: when events are populated and buttons are clicked it goes back to current month jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar-2

I have this problem in FullCalendar v2 where when I clicked the next or prev button(next/prev Month, technically). It will always go back to the current month. Please also note that the months are being populated with events upon clicking the next or previous button and even on page load.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i suggest you to post your sample html/js/css code

Comment: Without seeing your code or being able to reproduce the problem there is very little chance of that we can give you a good answer to the problem